# Javascript search validation

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
First name:
<input id="first_name" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
Last name:
<input id="last_name" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />

<input id="search_order" type="Submit" value="Find Order" />

<span id="warning" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">Please enter first and last name</span>

<script>
document.getElementById("search_order").addEventListener("click", search);
function search() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var name = fname + " " +  lname;
    if (fname == " " || lname == " ")
    {
        document.getElementById("warning").style.visibility = "visible";
        return;
    } else
        window.location = "http://bifoldsbidesign.com/?s=" + name + "&post_type=project";
}
</script>
```

Of which the search will always go through, even with the If statement checking if the values are empty?

The code is live on the site http://bifoldsbidesign.com/search-for-your-order/ if that is of any help.

Comment: @ShadowFiend — It isn't. `if` and `else` can be followed by a block **or** a single statement.

Comment: aw.. i thought the `}` is for the else its for the function.. my bad

Comment: The *return* inside the first if block is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to check that `firstname` and `lastname` are not empty, you should compare them to `""` rather than `" "`. The latter has a space between the two quotes.

```html
First name:
<input id="first_name" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" /> Last name:
<input id="last_name" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />

<input id="search_order" type="Submit" value="Find Order" />

<span id="warning" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">Please enter first and last name</span>

<script>
  document.getElementById("search_order").addEventListener("click", search);

  function search() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var name = fname + " " + lname;
    if (fname == "" || lname == "") {
      document.getElementById("warning").style.visibility = "visible";
      return;
    } else
      window.location = "http://bifoldsbidesign.com/?s=" + name + "&post_type=project";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to

```
if (fname.trim() == "" || lname.trim() == "")
```

Your condition will check for `" "` blank space not empty string. You can use [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) for not allowing white space as well

```js
document.getElementById("search_order").addEventListener("click", search);
function search() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var name = fname + " " +  lname;
    if (fname.trim() == "" || lname.trim() == "")
        document.getElementById("warning").style.visibility = "visible";
    else
        window.location = "http://bifoldsbidesign.com/?s=" + name + "&post_type=project";
}
```

```html
First name:
<input id="first_name" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
Last name:
<input id="last_name" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />

<input id="search_order" type="Submit" value="Find Order" />

<span id="warning" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">Please enter first and last name</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the fields contain a space. You want `fname.trim() == ""`
Where `trim()` first removes all whitespace characters and you check for an empty string.

You should also move your assignment of `name` to the else scope where it's actually used.